# Does twice continuously differentiable imply twice Fréchet differentiable?

Tags: calculus, analysis, derivatives

For simplicity assume that $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ for some open set $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{n}$. If $f$ is twice continuously differentiable, does that imply that $f$ is twice Fréchet (or totally) differentiable?

I know that once continuously differentiable implies once Fréchet differentiable (Theorem 6.2 in Munkres 'Analysis on manifolds'). Does simply applying this to the derivative of $f$ give that the implication in my question is true?

My second question is how does the second Fréchet derivative of $f$ differ from the Fréchet derivative of the gradient mapping of $f$ (i.e. the Hessian).

The issue is probably that I'm just still struggling with the concepts...

Edit: So the definition I have for $k$ times continuously differentiable is that all partial derivatives of order less than or equal to $k$ exists and are continuous. On [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothness#Multivariate_differentiability_classes) they say that this is equivalent to that the $k$th Fréchet derivative exists and is continuous.

Edit 2: And I now found relevant proofs in 'Differential Calculus' by Cartan.

Comment: I am a bit confused, what is your definition of twice continuously differentiable? Isn't that exactly twice totally differentiable and the second derivative is continuous?

Comment: No @SeverinSchraven. Twice continuously differentiable is that all second-order partial derivatives exists and are continuous.

Comment: I guess I am looking for something like the equivalence claimed here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothness#Multivariate_differentiability_classes